# How to sync git remotes

Tags: git, github

I managed to mess up my remotes and would like to get back in sync with origin. I have previously deleted all remotes and have manually re-added them.

My remotes are:

```
$ git remote -v show
origin  https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework (push)
truekonrads     git@github.com:truekonrads/mriv-metasploit.git (fetch)
truekonrads     git@github.com:truekonrads/mriv-metasploit.git (push)
```

I would like to update origin/master to latest version and then merge truekonrads/mirv-events branch into master. How do I do it?

is it possible to do it in a fashion that github keeps track of origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "update origin/master to latest version":

```
git fetch origin master
```

To "merge truekonrads/mirv-events branch into master":

```
git checkout master
git merge truekonrads/mirv-events
```

Not sure what you mean by github keeping track of origin. Your local repository is keeping track of `origin`. You could `git remote add github <URL>; git push github origin/master:latest_origin_master` to push a copy of `origin/master` up to github for safekeeping under the name `latest_origin_master`, but it's not clear if that's what you're wanting, especially since both `origin` and `truekonrads` are already on github.

Given your output above, it seems that `origin` and `truekonrads` are defined identically, which is redundant.

Comment: I had the wrong origin, you're correct. I managed to checkout -f the origin/master and then merge truekonrads/mirv-events to it, resolve conflicts and voila! What I meant by keeping track was - origin has no intention to use my pull requests, but I want to have latest features from there.